# Cannot empty the Deleted folder in outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com

I cannot empty my Deleted folder in Outlook.com. It has grown *enormous*—more than 300,000 messages. Many messages have been duplicated 10 or more times.

I simply want to completely purge this folder, but when I try to "empty" it, I get a variety of different messages such as

> there was a problem with the Outlook.com service...

I have even taken my computer in to a "geek" service, and they could not figure it out. 
Does anybody know how to completely purge a folder when the normal method does not work?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is because there are so many messages. Can try deleting, say, 100 at a time and see if that works?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you un-delete it, remove the messages, and then delete them.  You are able to do this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a bit?  As of right now, it's unclear as to what you mean.

Comment: so , if it hasn't Undo button , nothing .. idk :)